# Retrieve value of attribute in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a list of lines:

```
 <some_random_text="someval" my_val_="0.4" some_random_text_1="someval_">
 <some_random_text="someval" my_val_="0.8" some_random_text_1="someval_">
 <some_random_text="someval" my_val_="1.2" some_random_text_1="someval_">
```

and so on.

From each line, I want to return the numeric value given after my_val_. How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within this very rigid structure, what you want to do is quite easy using sed:

```
sed 's/.*my_val_="\([0-9.]\{1,\}\)".*/\1/' file
```

or using extended regular expressions:

```
sed -r 's/.*my_val_="([0-9.]+)".*/\1/' file
```

This captures the part you're interested in (the digits and dots between the quotes) and uses them to replace the contents of the line.

As mentioned in the comments (thanks), the switch to enable extended regular expressions differs between versions of sed. Out of habit, I tend to use `-r` but some implementations (such as BSD sed on OSX) work with `-E` instead. Others work with either `-r` or `-E` but [neither option is defined by the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html).

This *could* also be done in native bash (although I wouldn't recommend it...):

```
re='my_val_="([0-9.]+)"'
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < file
```

`=~` is the regex match operator. The captured digits and dots are stored in element `1` of the special array `BASH_REMATCH`.

---

The sed and bash approaches are subtly different, as the sed version will print all lines in the file, even if they don't match the pattern. If this is a problem, you can add the `-n` switch and a `p` at the end of the command to print matching lines:

```
sed -nr 's/.*my_val_="([0-9.]+)".*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: ++ for the pure-bash solution!

Comment: Nicely done; if you use `-E` instead of `-r`, it'll work on both Linux and OSX (GNU `sed` also supports `-E`; newer versions of FreeBSD now also support `-r`, but the OSX version, as of 10.10, does not; either way, a caveat remains: the extended regex flavors differ across these platforms).

Comment: @mklement0 I'm always a little reluctant to mention EREs in sed for this exact reason (I dread to think how many times the difference between implementations is discussed) but you are right, of course. I've edited my answer to mention the `-E` switch as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

With `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'my_val_="\K[^"]*' filename
```

`-o` so that `grep` only prints only the match, `-P` so that Perl-compatible regexes are used.

The `\K` in the regex removes from the match everything that was matched by the part of the regex that came before it; this has the effect of a lookbehind: only non-quote characters that come directly after `my_val_="` are matched.

Comment: Nicely done; `-P` requires _GNU_ `grep`; if that's not available, use `grep -o ' my_val_="[^"]*' filename | cut -d\" -f 2`.